# How to search substring from log field using the scripted fields in painless without regex

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to create to some scripted fields using painless by capturing some "keyword" in the log field, which is a long text field. for example, I have bunch of the log fields:

```
"Error: Duplicate entry in user1"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user2"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user1"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user3"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user2"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user1"

"Error: Duplicate entry in user3"
```

The painless I was using:

```
if (doc['log.keyword'].value == 'Duplicate entry') {
return "match";
}
return "No match";
```

to only capture the "Duplicate entry" error message regardless of userID, I am sure I need to use regex to do that. I am just wondering if there is another way to do it without using the regex. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of ways. you can try this:

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": 
      """
      if (doc["log.keyword"].value == null) return false;
      return doc["log.keyword"].value.contains("Duplicate entry");
      """
    }
  }
}
```

in kibana 5 triple quotes might not work. i don't remember exactly. just replace with single quotes

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I use the the script like this:

doc['log.keyword'].value.contains('Error')

It doesnt work. However, I just simply display all log messages using

doc['log.keyword'].value

It works, I am pretty sure the log messages have word "Error", I did not capture that. do you know what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: post your whole request (full dsl query) to ES

Comment: @Abdrey, I am using the scripted field, how can I post the full dsl query

Comment: if you return `params._source.log` what do you see?

Comment: I was using the painless instead of json. so where can I insert this params._source.log

Comment: @Andrey, is it possible to search string through params._source.field.contains('sample word')?